# React Tutorial and Sinatra API: Uncaught TypeError: this.props.data.map is not a function

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, reactjs

I know, there are hundreds of questions with the same title, but nothing helped my get a solution for my problem. so I worked through the official react js tutorial and build a small API with sinatra to test things.

so everything works really good. except of one error I see in the console when submitting a new "Joke" (called them jokes instead of comments ;)) via AJAX.

```
app.js:66 Uncaught TypeError: this.props.data.map is not a function
```

This happens when I click on submit. I logged the state when submitting the form and everything seems to be okay (array with the temporary objects).

so the new Joke is being added and written to the database. It works but i don't know why I'm getting the Uncaught TypeError in the console.

thanks in advance!

```
var JokeBox = React.createClass({
  loadJokesFromServer: function() {
    $.ajax({
      url: this.props.url,
      dataType: 'json',
      cache: false,
      success: function(data) {
        this.setState({data: data});
      }.bind(this),
      error: function(xhr, status, err) {
        console.error(this.props.url, status, err.toString());
      }.bind(this)
    });
  },
  handleJokeSubmit: function(joke) {
    var jokes = this.state.data;
    var tmpJoke = jQuery.extend({}, joke)
    tmpJoke.id  = new Date();
    tmpJoke.likes = 0;
    jokes.unshift(tmpJoke);
    this.setState({data: jokes}, function(){
      $.ajax({
        url: this.props.url,
        dataType: 'json',
        type: 'POST',
        data: joke,
        success: function(data) {
          this.setState({data: data});
        }.bind(this),
        error: function(xhr, status, err) {
          this.setState({data: jokes});
          console.error(this.props.url, status, err.toString());
        }.bind(this)
      });
    });
  },
  getInitialState: function() {
    return {data: []};
  },
  componentDidMount: function() {
    this.loadJokesFromServer();
    setInterval(this.loadJokesFromServer, this.props.pollInterval);
  },
  render: function() {
    return (
      <div className="jokes">
        <h1>Jokes</h1>
        <JokeForm onJokeSubmit={this.handleJokeSubmit} />
        <JokeList data={this.state.data} />
      </div>
    );
  }
});

var JokeList = React.createClass({
  render: function() {
    var jokeNodes = this.props.data.map(function(joke) {
      return (
        <Joke content={joke.content} key={joke.id} likes={joke.likes} />
      );
    });
    return (
      <div className="jokeList">
        {jokeNodes}
      </div>
    );
  }
});

var JokeForm = React.createClass({
  getInitialState: function() {
    return {content: ''};
  },
  handleContentChange: function(e) {
    this.setState({content: e.target.value});
  },
  handleSubmit: function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    var content = this.state.content.trim();
    if (!content) {
      return;
    }
    this.props.onJokeSubmit({content: content});
    this.setState({content: ''});
  },
  render: function() {
    return (
      <form className="jokesForm" onSubmit={this.handleSubmit}>
        <input
          type="text"
          placeholder="Your Joke!"
          value={this.state.content}
          onChange={this.handleContentChange}
        />
        <input type="submit" value="Send joke" />
      </form>
    );
  }
});

var Joke = React.createClass({
  render: function() {
    return (
      <div className="joke">
        <p className="jokeContent">{this.props.content}</p>
        <p className="jokeLikes">{this.props.likes}</p>
      </div>
    );
  }
});

ReactDOM.render(
  <JokeBox url="/api/jokes" pollInterval={2000} />,
  document.getElementById('app')
);
```

**// EDIT**

So I played around with the sample tutorial repo from the tutorial. I log the data in the handleSubmit in the success function right before the state is set. And I figured out: my data is ja object of the actual new Joke, in the sample tutorial it is an array of all comments. How could this be? I can't find my mistake...

Comment: Works well in the fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/mayank_shubham/69z2wepo/47701/

Comment: either your browser doesn't support Array.map, or for some reason this.state.data becomes not an array. But both cannot explain why first time is good.

Comment: Hi @Ron I'm working with Chrome 51 so map function should work. And I don't why it's working on jsfiddle. I'm using gulp-babel to transpile. could there be a problem? Some other ideas? Getting crazy :(

Comment: BTW you mutate your state by unshift()

Comment: you should check your responses , it must be array

Comment: @Utro I changed the state mutation with a concat to a new array. but the problem is the same.. Like I said, when I check the response in my console I get an Array with objects!

Comment: Maybe it is changed because the success function? success: function(data) {           this.setState({data: data});         }.bind(this),

Comment: @Ron : okay that data is a Object of the one new joke, not an array. But that is exactly the way they handle it in the Tutorial: could that be the problem?

Comment: @Utro You've been right. I've logged the "data" at the success function and it is an object instead of the array with all objects.. but.. my function looks exactly the same like the one at the tutorial. what am I doing wrong here?

Comment: can you elaborate handleJokeSubmit's work flow? why you do it like that

Comment: @Utro even if I cut of everything before the ajax request I get the same result.. and the ajax request is exactly the same like the one in the tutorial.

Comment: how response looks like

Comment: {content:'text', id:2131, likes:3} ?

Comment: right, looks like this: {content: "text text text", created: "2016-07-04T16:40:57+02:00", id: 27, likes: 0}

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/116384/discussion-between-utro-and-fngr).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**try**

```
handleJokeSubmit: function(joke) {

    let {data}= this.state;

    $.post(this.props.url, joke, res=>{
       this.setState({data:[res,...data]});
    })
   .fail( err=>alert('Error: ' + err.responseText));
}
```

**///EDIT** es5

```
handleJokeSubmit: function(joke) {

    var data = this.state.data;

    $.post(this.props.url, joke, function(res){
       this.setState({data:[res].concat(data)});
    }.bind(this))
   .fail( function(err){alert('Error: ' + err.responseText)});
}
```

Comment: that works! Now need to figure out whats wrong with mine!